# Как с помощью нескольких cout вывести текст друг под другом

Tags: c++

```
            #include <iostream>
             using namespace std;
              int main (){
             cout <<"Jason Statham";
            cout <<"Kellian Murphy";
               return 0;
                 }
```

Что надо здесь исправить чтобы текст был друг под другом, на отдельных строчках

Comment: Ну, просто выведите символ переноса строки, наверное?

Answer (score 2):

Либо

```
cout <<"Jason Statham" << endl;
cout <<"Kellian Murphy" << endl;
```

Либо

```
cout <<"Jason Statham\n";
cout <<"Kellian Murphy\n";
```